# MSK Kafka connect commit of offsets timed out

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am using Kafka connect to take messages from an MSK cluster, and put them on a Kinesis firehose as per https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kinesis-kafka-connector-msk/

I have the setup working, but when I try to put large amounts of messages through the system I get the warning

```
WARN WorkerSinkTask{id=mytopicconnector-0} Commit of offsets timed out (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:222)
```

Kafka version is 2.6.0

I'm fairly new to Kafka so am unsure on what the best approach is to solve this. I have thought about increasing the kafka connect worker timeout but that doesn't quite seem right.

Comment: I have also same issue, is there any update?